# How to retrieve of data from MySQL server for all items in a list in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I am making a graph based web progrom. I am using nodejs. 
I have a list of keys calls map which stores ID of vertices.
I want to retrieve the name of these vertices from MySQL using the ID. I have found a solution but I am not sure if it will work every time. This is my code.

```
for(var i=0;i<map.length;++i){
    con.query('SELECT * FROM station WHERE id='+map[i],function(err,result,field){
        if(err)
            console.log("ERROR 3");
        else{
            result.forEach(function(r){
                stationName.push(r.name);
            })
            if(stationName.length==map.length){
                console.log(stationName);
                res.render('route/showroute.ejs',{stationName: stationName});
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I was wonder is it possible that my last map query loads before other query which may cause station name to be stored in wrong order. I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `async` `await` function

```
var getDataById = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM station WHERE id=' + id, function (err, result, field) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR 3");
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};

(async function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
        var data = await getDataById(map[i]);
        data.forEach(function (r) {
            stationName.push(r.name);
        });
        if (stationName.length == map.length) {
            console.log(stationName);
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are worried about the query-function being asynchronous, and it is, but only with regard to what comes after the function. You're putting your stationNames into a new array inside the callback function which will be executed in sequence.